# how do you use variable names in plot and or model creation in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame called df:

```
put(df)
structure(list(load = c(1L, 18L, 36L, 72L, 108L, 144L, 216L), 
    throughput = c(64.9, 995.9, 1652.4, 1853.2, 1828.9, 1775, 
    1702.2)), .Names = c("load", "throughput"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

xv<-c("load")
yv<-c("throughput")
```

I need to be able to use the variable names to create models and or plot like this:

```
usl.model<-usl(yv~xv,data=df)
```

I get this error:

```
Warning in usl(yv ~ xv, data = df) :
  'data' has only a few values; the result might not be accurate
Warning in usl(yv ~ xv, data = df) :
  'data' has no row where 'xv' = 1; switching method from 'default' to 'nlxb'
Warning: Error in /: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If I use

```
usl.model<-usl(throughput~load,data=df) ##column names, it works.
```

I need to be able to use the variable names. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yv/xv is treated as variables in data frame `df`. See `?formula` for details. You can use eval-parse instead:

```
library(usl)
df <- structure(list(load = c(1L, 18L, 36L, 72L, 108L, 144L, 216L), 
               throughput = c(64.9, 995.9, 1652.4, 1853.2, 1828.9, 1775,1702.2)),
               .Names = c("load", "throughput"), class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -7L))
xv<-c("load")
yv<-c("throughput")
eval(parse(text=paste0("usl.model<-usl(",yv,'~',xv,",data=df)")))
```

Besides, `df` is not a good name for data frame as it is also a build-in function.

Comment: `usl.model <- usl(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)` would be better

Comment: @rawr, how would I create a plot based on variable names? plot(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)?

Comment: @rawr, worked thank you, can you put it as an answer?

Comment: @rawr Thanks! That's why I also refer to `formula`. If the expression is more that a formula, eval-parse always works.

Comment: @Rawr, I spoke to quickly, I'm getting this error: Warning messages:
1: In usl(as.formula(paste(yv, "~", xv)), data = df) :
  'data' has no row where 'Volume' = 1; switching method from 'default' to 'nlxb'
2: 'data' shows efficiency > 1; this looks almost too good to be true

Comment: @rawr, yes, the problem was with the data. Thanks again.